# Thymeleaf - Set attribute in meta tag with conditional

Tags: thymeleaf

I would like to set the content of my "robots" tag depending on an attribute returned with my model.  In my back end return statements, I have one place where I return the following snippet, and some places where I do not set that attribute at all.

```
model.addAttribute("robotsMetaTag", "all");
return "pages/index";
```

I would like to make it so the attribute looks like this if I am setting robotsMetaTag:

```
<meta name="robots" content="all"/>
```

and like this if there robotsMetaTag is not set:

```
<meta name="robots" content="none"/>
```

---

Currently, I am doing the following:

```
<meta name="robots" th:attr="content=${robotsMetaTag}"/>
```

This works for the pages where I am returning a value for robotsMetaTag, but I would like a default case where if nothing is set/returned then I want the default to be "none".  I've been trying to get th:attrappend to work for me for this, but I'm getting parsing errors with the following:

```
<meta name="robots" th:attrappend="content=${${robotsMetaTag} == null}?none:${robotsMetaTag}"/>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out this

```
<meta name="robots" th:attr="content=${robotsMetaTag==null?'none':robotsMetaTag}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I got the same thing as you just a minute before you posted... sometimes you just gotta ask for help to realize what you were doing wrong!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since `th:content` is a [supported attribute](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-value-to-specific-attributes) and Thymeleaf supports the the [elvis operator](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#default-expressions-elvis-operator), you can simplify your expression to this and achive the same result:

```
<meta name="robots" th:content="${robotsMetaTag} ?: 'none'" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out... I was playing too fast and loose with my curly bois...  This is what I was looking for.  It adds a default case if "robotsMetaTag" is not set.

```
<meta name="robots" th:attrappend="content=${robotsMetaTag == null} ? none : ${robotsMetaTag}"/>
```